# Composer avoid installing sub-dependency

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, composer-php, conflict, conflicting-libraries

I have installed on my composer project the `aws/aws-sdk-php` library, and i want to add the `googleads/googleads-php-lib` library but it won't let me because the first library has a sub-dependency called `guzzlehttp/psr7`. And the second librariy too.

How can i manage to install both libraries and avoiding the conflict?

Comment: This is a really tough issue. You may have to bite the bullet, decide which is more important and go with that one. This is a very unfortunate situation. Unless you're willing to put both code packets back to a point where their dependencies match. Or if there is a setting that lets you circumvent this.

Comment: Turns out that i was able to get a version of the first package where the sub-dependency doesn't demand a superior version of the other ones,It was indeed a tough decission. I wonder if this is becoming a recurrent topic because i had trouble finding information about this.

Comment: It's the one flaw with package managers. Otherwise they're pretty great. I've worked in a couple different languages and PHP seems to be the most flagrant with people not updating their code when dependent packages get updated. Also, composer doesn't really have a "Which version would you like to use" kind of thing, it just fails.